The term './darknet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
I was running the yolov3 on custom dataset on my local laptop after doing everything when I am running this final command
./darknet detector train DATASET/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet53.conv.74

And I am using windows power shell I am getting an error which is
./darknet : The term './darknet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./darknet detector train DATASET/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet5 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./darknet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So how can I resolve this error
I have tried changing the system enviroment variable path and also I have tried running some command but it Still throwing an same error So what should I try

Use Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) instead of PowerShell:
Sometimes, running the same command in Command Prompt instead of PowerShell can resolve issues with Unix-like commands.
Open Command Prompt and run:
./darknet detector train DATASET/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet53.conv.74


That implies that ./darknet.exe might work too.

The command you mention running:
./darknet detector train DATASET/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg  darknet53.conv.74

...implies you are running the old abandoned AlexeyAB repo.  Note that repo was abandoned in July 2021, just over 3 years ago.  The new repo is this one:

https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

Part of the installation step for that repo will install darknet.exe to a proper location, such as C:\Program Files\Darknet\bin\darknet.exe, and the NSIS package installation also attempts to put that location in your PATH.  This way, you can run darknet.exe from any location without running into problems.
I strongly suggest you upgrade to a newer and supported version of Darknet/YOLO.
If you have further question, note the following:

The Darknet/YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/
The Darknet/YOLO discord server:  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW


does this also work same as alexeyab was  used to do and is the whole process same

Yes, it is the same, but with an additional 3 years of additional fixes and optimizations.
